# Python Thread run function return value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multithreading, dataframe

I have pandasDataframes and i would like to apply a function on it. I would like to have many iterations, so i think it would be nice to use multiple `threads`.

This is how it looks like:

```
def my_function(data_inputs_train):

    #..... do something with dataframe....
    #..... group by for loops etc .......
    #..... create new dataframe.....
    return newPandasDataFrame

class myThread (threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self, threadID, data_inputs_train):

      threading.Thread.__init__(self)

      self.threadID = threadID
      self.data_inputs_train = data_inputs_train

   def run(self):
      result_df = my_function(data_inputs_train)

thread1 = myThread(1, data_inputs_train)
thread2 = myThread(2, data_inputs_train)
```

So both thread should return a new dataframe, and after both thread finished i would like to concatenate the two result that returned from two thread.

How can i do that? How could is return any object from the `run()` function, and how can i access it in my `thread1`object?

Thank you!

**UPDATE by first answer but its not works, there are indent problems too.**

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self, threadID, name, sleep, cust_type, data_inputs_train):

      threading.Thread.__init__(self)

      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.sleep = sleep
      self.cust_type = cust_type
      self.data_inputs_train = data_inputs_train
      #here i need to get the newPandasDataFrame object.
      result_df = fdp.optimze_score_and_cl(data_inputs_train)

    def returnTheData(self):
        return result_df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the base of your program.. I am just using example data to show how you could set it up

```
    def myFunction(x):
       df = pd.DataFrame(['1', '2'], columns = ['A'])
       return df

    class myThreads(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, threadID, name, sleep, cust_type, data_inputs_train):
           threading.Thread.__init__(self)
           self.threadID = threadID
           self.name = name
           self.sleep = sleep
           self.cust_type = cust_type

           # call the methods you need on your data...
           self.data_inputs_train = myFunction(data_inputs_train)

         def returnTheData(self):
           return self.data_inputs_train


df = pd.DataFrame(['1'], columns = ['A'])
thread1 = myThreads(1, "EX1", 1, 'EX', df)
thread2 = myThreads(2, "IN1", 2, 'IN', df)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()

df1 = thread1.returnTheData()
df2 = thread2.returnTheData()

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

You declare your threads.. Start them and basically have them run what ever you want..

> join()

Allows the main function to wait until all the threads have finished their processing.

> df2 = thread2.returnTheData()

And you just call a function to return the data that you  need.

The working code

> https://repl.it/repls/ClearHugeOutlier

Comment: sorry, it's not clear.. there arent run() ins your answer isn't it problem?

Comment: // call the methods you need on your data...  
under initialize is where you would call any  functions that would work on your data.

Comment: it's not good like this :( sorry. my function is outside of my class.. i cannot call it in the init function of the thread.

Comment: You maybe misunderstood me. I dont want to return the original dataframe. the function i called in the thread, would create another dataframe object, after i manipulated the original dataframe.

Comment: yes i think my answer still holds good.. let me edit it to mimic your program

Comment: updated my question. please check it. your code this wax unfortunetly has bad indentation level also. :(

Comment: i dont want to return the data_inputs_train object because the myFunction wouldn't return that. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200075/discussion-between-yatish-kadam-and-solarenqu).